# Cmake problems after upgrading to MacOS 13.0

Tags: python, macos, opencv, cmake

As mentioned on the title, CMake seems to be broken after upgrading to MacOS 13.0.

Trying to install something that requires Cmakes takes unusually long then the following pop-up shows up.

```
“CMake” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash. 

This file was downloaded on an unknown date.  # this txt is grey and smaller font

Pop-up Options
1. Move to Trash  2. Cancel
```

Steps to reproduce Err

1. Cloned EasyOCR

   1.1 git clone ...
2. Made Python venv

   2.0. cd EasyOCR/

   2.1. python3 -m venv venv

   2.2. source venv/bin/activate

   2.3. venv info

   ```
   python --version && pip --version
   # output   
   Python 3.10.6
   pip 22.3 from ...  # path to venv dir
   ```
3. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
# requirements.txt content
torch
torchvision>=0.5
opencv-python-headless<=4.5.4.60
scipy
numpy
Pillow
scikit-image
python-bidi
PyYAML
Shapely
pyclipper
ninja
```

4. After a while, the aforementioned pop-up, shows up. Clicking on either option will result in the following error.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python-headless
  Building wheel for opencv-python-headless (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for opencv-python-headless (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
        File "/private/var/folders/5h/36chnb_s3b5fpqmqgt_7cz_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ea_5u80v/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 613, in setup
          cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
        File "/private/var/folders/5h/36chnb_s3b5fpqmqgt_7cz_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ea_5u80v/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 141, in __init__
          self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
        File "/private/var/folders/5h/36chnb_s3b5fpqmqgt_7cz_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ea_5u80v/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 95, in get_cmake_version
          raise SKBuildError(
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      
      Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python-headless
Failed to build opencv-python-headless
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python-headless, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Any thoughts on how to fix or get around this? This is the first time I see this pop up.

Comment: Same problem with https://github.com/codypiersall/pynng/tree/master/

Comment: Same problem, same use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pip package is broken on macOS 13 prior to CMake 3.24.2 due to improper code signing. You should upgrade CMake in your virtual environment by running:

```
$ python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
$ python -m pip install -U 'cmake>=3.24.2'
```

As CMake is *extremely* backwards compatible, it should be safe. You can also add `cmake>=3.24.2` to your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Did this on macOS 13.4.1 and the result is the same. In my case it fails when I run `python -m pip install simplejpeg` and it does this whether I use the stock python 3.9 or homebrew 3.11

Comment: Maybe this does not work on Apple Silicon due to conflicting code signatures of the CMake.app that can be found at /private/var/folders/xn/51rpq1b940773yhg9f3cjfkh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-oq563g3d/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app (when the error pops up) and opened in Apparency.

Comment: I did this on macOS 13.4.1 and it worked for me. The first command gave me the error: `ERROR: conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.` but I ignored it and did the second command anyway, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

@hawk: I was able to solve this by cloneing [simplejpeg](https://gitlab.com/jfolz/simplejpeg/) with git, then using pip to install it directly `pip install .`